# Sum of all slices along given axis of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape (3,12,7,5). I would like to have the sum of all slices along the first axis of this array.

```
data = np.random.randint(low=0, high=8000, size=3*12*7*5).reshape(3,12,7,5)

data[0,...].sum()
data[1,...].sum()
data[2,...].sum()

np.array((data[0,...].sum(), data[1,...].sum(), data[2,...].sum()))
```

First, I thought this should be possible using `np.sum(data, axis=...)` but it is not.

How do I perform this calculation in a single shot. What is the numpy magic?

Comment: `np.sum(data, axis=...)` should work

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't. I edited the question. arg! it does!

Comment: I thought that it would be axis=(0,1,2) and had no success. This is why I posted the question. Why is it axis=(1,2,3)? Isn't this contrary to how numpy is enumerating it's axis?

Comment: Before the tuple version of axis was added, we used to do `data.sum(axis=-1).sum(axis=-1)...`.  That is, just repeated sums on desire axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a generic ndarray, you could reshape into a 2D array, keeping the number of elements along the first axis same and *merging* all of the remaining axes as the second axis and finally sum along that axis, like so -

```
data.reshape(data.shape[0],-1).sum(axis=1)
```

For a `4D` array, you could include the axes along which the summation is to be performed. So, to solve our case, we would have -

```
data.sum(axis=(1,2,3))
```

This could be extended to make it work for generic ndarrays by creating a tuple of appropriate axis IDs and thus avoid reshaping, like so -

```
data.sum(axis=tuple(np.arange(1,data.ndim)))
```

Comment: I thought that it would be axis=(0,1,2) and had no success. This is why I posted the question. Why is it axis=(1,2,3)? Isn't this contrary to how numpy is enumerating it's axis?

Comment: @ThomasMöbius Well you are sum-reducing the last three axes, that's why  we need to list out those axes with `np.sum`. Just remember that the axis we mention with `np.sum` is/are the axis/axes along which all elements would be summed. In our case, it would be last three axes.